# How to use elements returned from browser.elements()?

Tags: javascript, element, webdriver-io

The following code is designed to gather the elements having their `href attribute` beginning with "/assets/css/" as per [this](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html).
Yet the first attempt to access either `browser.elementIdAttribute(iter1, 'href').value` or `browser.elementIdAttribute(iter1, 'href')` crashes with the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

```js
var styleSheetsElems = browser.elements('[href^="/assets/css/"]').value; 

for (let iter1 in styleSheetsElems)
{ 
    console.log( browser.elementIdAttribute(iter1, 'href').value );
};
```

- Here I can see that the elements exist( I can traverse the Array though I don't try to print).

My understanding is that ***The populating of `styleSheetsElems` should vouch for the elements existing and having an href ...***

printing .`elements('[xyz]')` results in

```
{ state: 'success',
  sessionId: '652f9f1c-6cad-42d7-89a3-e09a1acbd1af',
  hCode: 1951176523,
  value: 
  [{ ELEMENT: '11' },
   { ELEMENT: '12' },
   { ELEMENT: '88' }],
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  selector: '[xyz]',
  _status: 0 }
```

so no luck there... digging further

Comment: Have you printed out iter1 ... what's it's value before the crash?

Comment: it's 0 (first element). But if I try to skip it it crashes on element 1...

Comment: So - it sounds like both element 0 and 1 don't contain 'href'?   How about printing out `browser.elements('[href^="/assets/css/"]')` to see what all the elements actually are?

Comment: updating post so I can add code

Answer (score 2):

the proper syntax for the query was as follow:

```
var styleSheetsElems = browser.elements('[href^="/assets/css/"]').value; 

for (let iter1 in styleSheetsElems)
{ 
    console.log( browser.elementIdAttribute(styleSheetsElems[iter1].ELEMENT, 'href').value );
};
```

A few tests that helped out were printing out the content of the array as per [GreenAsJade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554807/greenasjade)'s suggestion.. Then realizing I was making the assumption that 'iter1' was the same as the elementID stored in that array. Many thanks!

Comment: Cool :)   Moral of the story: print stuff out to test your assumptions (aka "understandings" ;) ) .   I must say that the documentation is poor on this point: I haven't used this library, and saw the comment about '.ELEMENT' in the doc and couldn't see what it was talking about, so it's easy to see how you were confused.